# Saying Divrei Torah by a Seudah -- also for Women?

Tags: torah-study, women, meal-seudah

There is a mitzvah of saying Divrei Torah at a Seudah (meal). The rule says that any table that didn't have Divrei Torah said on it is as if someone ate from "Zivchei Masim" ("sacrifices to the dead"). (See one source for this in M"B Siman 170 Sif-Katan 1.)

Over there the language is "mitzvah al col adam" ("it is a mitzva on every person").

Does this mitzvah include women? If a group of women eat together must they also say Divrei Torah in order that it should be that it is as if they eat from "Zivchei Masim". Are there any sources that speak about this?

Comment: What does the word "mitzva" mean in this context? I doubt this is one of the 613. Note: The most famous source for this (and, I suspect, the earliest) is Pirkei Avot.

Comment: @IsaasMoses I'm quoting the lashon of the M"B. If you want to know what mitzvah means in this context then I recommend you ask the question I think it would be a good one (there are many cases the word "mitzvah" is used and it's not one of the 613.) I also had a similar question and figured someone here would jump right on that point. However I assumed then that the person would realize that's the lashon of the M"B. I quoted only the M"B because that's what I remembered where it is but true Pirkei Avos is certainly the earliest makor.

Comment: @Yehoshua Not quite. In Avos deRabbi Natan (N2:34) we have the same statement in the name of Rabbi Elazar ben Rabbi Tzadok who lived a number of years before Rabbi Shimon (bar Yochai) who is the quote's source in the Mishna in Avot.

Comment: @DoubleAA you know after I hit the button "Add Comment" I knew someone would find something earlier but I let it go anyway. How did you find it? Or did you know this from before?

Comment: @DoubleAA - "N2:34" = Nusach 2, §34? I'm assuming that the version I have in my Oz veHadar is the primary nusach (נוסחת הגר"א). Do you know where the secondary nusach is published? Is the statement word for word the same as Avot 3:3?

Comment: @ShimonbM See http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=38247&st=&pgnum=108

Comment: @DoubleAA No response to my question?